# Data in Lookup Columns goes missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, lookup-column

We have SharePoint Online and within one site a Document Library. 
Within the Library are 8 Lookup columns that reference lists within the same site.

When a Document gets uploaded to the Library, a Workflow will run.

This Workflow waits for the document to be checked in by the person who uploads it, then checks the document out, renames it to conform with a naming standard,assigns an owner(whoever created the document) and checks the document in.

However, once the Workflow has run the lookup fields are all blank.

Can't figure out how or why this happens but would appreciate any ideas on where to look or what to check. Thanks in advance

Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have enabled “Require Check Out”. It will check out the file automatically when uploading a file to the library.
[image]

The file item is created after uploading. If the workflow is started automatically when an item is created, the workflow will be run automatically after the user uploads the file. **Ensure the file is checked out when uploading**.

Add "pause for a duration" action at the begging of your workflow, make it pause for a while (e.g. 1 minute). Check the results.

Comment: JoannaW - Thanks for this suggestion. I've gone back to the Workflow owner and asked them to make this change. I take it the suggestion is that the Workflow is starting before the Item is properly created ? Thanks , Dan